# Movie recyclerview above keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bottom-nav-view

I have my custom BottomSheetDialogFragment.Inside this dialog I have custom edittext and recyclerview.My goal is to move reyclerview above a keyboard,when it' showing. Here is a my custom edittext code

```
public class WrappedEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

public WrappedEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrappedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public WrappedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Nullable
private View wrapper;

@Nullable
public View getWrapper() {
    return wrapper;
}

@Override
public void getFocusedRect(Rect r) {
    if (wrapper != null) {
        wrapper.getFocusedRect(r);
        return;
    }
    super.getFocusedRect(r);
}

@Override
public boolean getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r, Point globalOffset) {
    if (wrapper != null)
        return wrapper.getGlobalVisibleRect(r, globalOffset);
    return super.getGlobalVisibleRect(r, globalOffset);
}

public void setWrapper(@Nullable View wrapper) {
    this.wrapper = wrapper;
}
```

I'm using this code like this

```
 searchView.setWrapper(rootView);
    searchView.setOnFocusChangeListener((view1, b) -> {
        if(searchView.getWrapper()==null)
            searchView.setWrapper(rootView);
    });





<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/slide_menu_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/close_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_p_30"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_p_40"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_p_4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_p_10"
            android:background="@drawable/slide_menu_title_line" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_conainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_p_30"
        android:layout_below="@+id/close_view">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_p_30"
            android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_geo_medium"
            android:text="@string/insert_gif"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_p_14" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_p_38"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_conainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_p_30"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_p_30"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_p_24"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_p_24"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_p_8"
            android:background="@mipmap/search_icon" />

        <app.singltone.giphy.WrappedEditText
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_p_35"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_p_10"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_geo_medium"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/find_gif"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#59000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_p_14" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_layout"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:saveEnabled="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

rootView is a main view in xml file.This code working perfect only first time,but when user closed keyboard and then opened it again ,this code does not working.
Is a any way to solve this problem? or is this a correct solution?
Thanks

Comment: try putting a recyclerview within a scrollview, which will automatically push your edittext and show above the keyboard layout

Comment: I tried it but not working